# cake php: correct url to action

Tags: forms, cakephp, routes

I have two URLs for one action and each should generate different views.

e.g.:
/abc -> connects with controller x, action y, view = 0

/def -> connects with controller x, action y, view = 1

this works fine with

Router::connect('/abc', array('controller' => 'x 'action' => 'y', 'view' => 0));

Router::connect('/def', array('controller' => 'x 'action' => 'y', 'view' => 1));

---

but now there is that problem:

I have a formular, which should send its data to /def or /abc.
How can I manually set, which route should be used?

---

edit:

$form->create('Model', array('url' => array('action' => 'index', 'view' => '1'))); // def

$form->create('Model', array('url' => array('action' => 'index', 'view' => '0'))); // abc

both leads me to /controller/index and not to /def or /abc

Answer (score 2):

```
Router::connect('/def', array('controller' => 'x' action' => 'y', 'view' => 1), array('pass' => array('view')));
```

then

```
if($this->params['view']){
   // its 1
} else{
   //its 0
}
```

Comment: yes, that works for me. but how do i correctly select the target-url for the formular?

Comment: $this->Html->link('foo', '/def'); not sure what you asking